# Express.js server cannot render css and js file

Tags: node.js, express

I am following a tutorial on YouTube, about NODE.js and Express.js. I have gotten to the section on Express and cannot render the CSS and JS file of a webpage. The index.html and logo.svg files are rendered to the server. Any help would be appreciated to render the CSS and JS files. My file structure is:

```
Main_Folder
  |navbar-app
    |index.html
  |public
    |browser-app.js
    |styles.css
    |logo.svg
  |app.js
```

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.static('./public'))

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './navbar-app/index.html'))
})

app.all('*', (req,res) => {
    res.status(404).send('<h2>Resource not found</h2>');
})

app.listen((5000), () => {
    console.log('server')
})
```

Comment: Static files to be printed on front end can be loaded on by putting `express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/path'))` in target path. [Check here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing importing static files(`app.use(express.static(__dirname))` ), which must be placed before app calling methods, like so :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.static('./public'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './navbar-app/index.html'))
})
...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I tried adding the code and static files are still not shown.

Comment: Just a note, the solution was adding "type = text/css" to the html file. That allowed the css file to be rendered.